# The XML file which I generate contain unwanted spaces between the words

Tags: python, csv

I updated my question :
I have a XML file which contains several titles. But, these title are in french, not in English, like this :

```
    <entity name="MissionTemplate">
  <string name="code" required="true" title="Bond Restitution Date"/>
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Description"/>
```

I would like to translate each title in English. To make it, I have a translation's CSV file which I have to use to translate the XML file. This CSV file isn't in the final application, just in local in my computer, it's just use to get the correct translations. Here is a sample :

```
Table;Champ;Anglais;Français

"HeaderTable8011405";"Code";"Code";"Code"

"HeaderTable8011405";"Activity_Type";"Auction,Mission";"Vente,Mission"

"HeaderTable8011405";"Activity_Type";"Activity Type";"Type activité"
...
```

I have also another CSV translation's file which contains the correspondence between the English words and french words. It's inside the final application. So, when the user will change the language, this file is using to translate the application. Here is a sample of this file :

```
"key","message","comment","context"
"Code","Code",,
"Auction,Mission","Vente,Mission",, 
"Activity Type","Type activité",,
...
```

I have to get the french title in the XML file and search it in the local CSV file (the first CSV translation's file). If the french title is there, I copy the English translation and I replace the french translation in the XML file. Finally, I must add a new row in the second CSV translation's file (the file which use to switch between English and french) with, at the first column, the English word and, at the second column, the french word.
To summarize, there is 3 files : a XML file (contains several titles), a CSV local file which contains good translations (isn't in my application, just use to get the correct English translation), and another CSV file which contains correspondence between English and french words (it use inside the application to switch between two languages : English and french).

I can hand-make this previous tasks, because it's so cumbersome and time-consuming...

So, I tried to create a Python program to make this task instead of me.
Here is the code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv


xml_file = input("Give here the name of the XML file which you want translate : ")
translations_file = input("Give here the name of the translation's file : ")
final_translations_file = input("Give here the name of the final translation's file : ")

# Reading the data inside the xml
# file to a variable under the name
# data
with open('MissionTemplate_model.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()


# Passing the stored data inside
# the beautifulsoup parser, storing
# the returned object
data = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")


# Title list
title_list = []

# Get each title in the XML file
for element in data.find_all():
    if 'title' in element.attrs:
        title_content = element['title']
        title_list.append(title_content)

# Check if the title is translated
missing_translations = []
translation_list= pd.read_csv(translations_file,delimiter=';')
translation_fr_list = translation_list.Français
translation_en_list = translation_list.Anglais
header = ['key', 'message', 'comment', 'context']
additional_data = []
for each_title in title_list:
    found = False
    lineNb = 0
    for each_translation in translation_fr_list:
        # It's all right
        if each_title == each_translation: 
            found = True
            translation_en = translation_en_list[lineNb]
            translation_fr = each_translation
            for element in data.find_all():
                if 'title' in element.attrs and element['title'] == translation_fr:
                    # Set the title in the XML file
                    element['title'] = translation_en
                    # Add couple of translation in the additional data's list
                    additional_data.append([translation_en,translation_fr,None,None])
            continue
        lineNb = lineNb + 1
    # Else
    if found == False:
        missing_translations.append(each_title)
# Load the CSV file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv(final_translations_file)
# Create a DataFrame from additional_data
additional_df = pd.DataFrame(additional_data, columns=header)
# Add the news datas at the end of the existing DataFrame
updated_df = pd.concat([df, additional_df], ignore_index=True)
# Save the updated DataFrame in the CSV file 
updated_df = updated_df.applymap(lambda x: ' '.join(x.strip().split()) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
updated_df.to_csv(final_translations_file, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')






# Load the CSV file using pandas
df = pd.read_csv(final_translations_file, sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)

# Function to check if a string begins and ends by double quotes
def has_quotes(s):
    return s.startswith('"') and s.endswith('"')

# Explore the lines of the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Check if the two first columns doesn't already have double quotes
    if not has_quotes(row[0]) and not has_quotes(row[1]):
        # Modify this line
        df.iloc[index, :2] = '"' + df.iloc[index, :2] + '"'

# Save the modified DataFrame as new csv file 
df.to_csv(final_translations_file, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')


# Open again the file in read/write mode
with open(final_translations_file, "r+") as f:
    # Read the current content of the file

    content = f.read()

    # Find the first line's position (up to the first occurence of \n)
    first_line_end = content.find("\n") + 1

    # Extract the first line and check if it contains double quotes
    first_line = content[:first_line_end]
    if not has_quotes(first_line):
        modified_first_line = '"' + '","'.join(first_line.strip().split(",")) + '"\n'

        # Replace the first line by the modified 
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(modified_first_line)
        f.write(content[first_line_end:])






# Replace the content of the XML original XML file by the modified content
modified_xml_file = data.prettify()
with open(xml_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(modified_xml_file)

# Write the missing translations in a file
with open('missing_translations.txt','w') as f:
    missing_translations.insert(0,xml_file+":\n") # Add the name of the file at the begining of the missing translations's list
    missing_translations_string = '\n'.join(missing_translations) # Tranform the list to string
    f.write(missing_translations_string)
```

It's all right, but there is unwanted spaces between each words in the second CSV file (the CSV file which use inside the application), like :

```
"key","message","comment","context"
"Code","Code",,
"Auction,    Mission","Vente,    Mission",, 
"Activity    Type","Type    activité",,
```

I tried lot of solutions, remove each spaces after the file was created using the split() function, but it doesn't work...

Could you help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hi. I have a hard time following your question because none of the samples you've shared seem to relate to one another: `Désignation` ≠ `Code` ≠ `Type    Activité`. That said, I think I still get the gist of the question. Can you edit the question and update the samples so that they all relate? Also, please include a small (maybe hand-edited) sample of XML we can run the code against.

Comment: `It's all right, but in the final translation's there is 4 spaces between each words:` Is this in the CSV or XML file? It looks like CSV, but from your question, it seems like the final translation is an XML file?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read all the code and see where extra spaces may or may not be inserted.

Instead, I suggest you rethink the structure of your program.  In addition to not using Pandas and making the logic/loop simpler I recommend breaking the program up into distinct parts:

1. create French→English look-up dict
2. iterate XML and end up with translated and missing
3. write out translated and missing files
4. modify XML, then write it out

Probably the biggest change will be just using a dict to store the translations you already have.

Starting with this translations.csv file:

```
| Table              | Champ | Anglais       | Français      |
|--------------------|-------|---------------|---------------|
| HeaderTable8011405 | Code  | Code          | Code          |
| HeaderTable8011405 | ???   | Designation   | Désignation   |
| HeaderTable8011405 | ???   | River         | Rivière       |
| HeaderTable8011405 | ???   | Activity Type | Type Activité |
```

Create a dict where each key is the French word and its value is the English word:

```py
import csv

translator: dict[str, str] = {}
with open("translations.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader)  # discard header
    for row in reader:
        translator[row[3]] = row[2]

print(translator)
```

```py
{
    'Code':          'Code', 
    'Désignation':   'Designation', 
    'Rivière':       'River', 
    'Type Activité': 'Activity Type',
}
```

Now you can loop over the elements of the XML once, and check each title against the translator dict.  I only use BeautifulSoup for broken/messy HTML; for valid XML I like the standard library's ElementTree module.  I also added my own logic if the element doesn't have a title (skip and move to next), or if the translation doesn't exist (append to missing, then move to next).

Starting with this input.xml file:

```xml
<root>
    <string name="foobar" namecolumn="baz" /> <!-- no title -->
    <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Désignation" />
    <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Rivière" />
    <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Ordinateur" />
    <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Type Activité" />
    <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Vélo" />
</root>
```

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml_input = "input.xml"
tree = ET.parse(xml_input)
root = tree.getroot()

# A list of French titles with no English translation
missing: list[str] = []

# A list of French titles and their English translations
translated: list[tuple[str, str]] = []

for elem in root.findall("string"):
    french = elem.get("title")
    if french is None:
        continue

    english = translator.get(french)
    if english is None:
        missing.append(french)
        continue

    translated.append((french, english))
```

Looking at missing and translated:

```py
print(missing)
```

```py
[
    'Ordinateur', 
    'Vélo'
]
```

```py
print(translated)
```

```py
[
    ('Désignation',   'Designation'),
    ('Rivière',       'River'),
    ('Type Activité', 'Activity Type')
]
```

Writing those to their own files looks straight-forward:

```py
with open("output-translated.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["key", "message", "comment", "context"])
    for row in translated:
        writer.writerow([row[1], row[0], None, None])
```

```
| key           | message       | comment | context |
|---------------|---------------|---------|---------|
| Designation   | Désignation   |         |         |
| River         | Rivière       |         |         |
| Activity Type | Type Activité |         |         |
```

```py
with open("output-missing.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(f"{xml_input}:\n")
    for x in missing:
        f.write(x + "\n")
```

```
input.xml:
Ordinateur
Vélo
```

To change the XML and save it, the ElememtTree class I started with makes this easy.  I'll just copy-paste the XML-looping-code from earlier, remove the missing and translated lists, and add the crucial `elem.set("title", english)` call to replace the title attribute with the English translation:

```py
for elem in root.findall("string"):
    french = elem.get("title")
    if french is None:
        continue

    english = translator.get(french)
    if english is None:
        continue

    elem.set("title", english)

ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

That yields the final output.xml file:

```xml
<root>
  <string name="foobar" namecolumn="baz" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Designation" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="River" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Ordinateur" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Activity Type" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Vélo" />
</root>
```

If you wanted to remove elements that didn't have a title or couldn't be translated, remove the element from its parent (root) with `root.remove(elem)`:

```py
for elem in root.findall("string"):
    french = elem.get("title")
    if french is None:
        root.remove(elem)
        continue

    english = translator.get(french)
    if english is None:
        root.remove(elem)
        continue

    elem.set("title", english)

ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-8")
```

```xml
<root>
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Designation" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="River" />
  <string name="description" namecolumn="true" title="Activity Type" />
</root>
```